# using a blob on my web application

Tags: blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I was reading API of Windows Azure and I have a question about blobl storage service.For instance, is it possible to use an image from my blob storage account for my website. I saw  how to access to a blob via a browser.This is something like that:

```
http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
```

I didn't test it, so I don't know what it returns, but how can I use this blob?

Answer (score -1):

Containers are similar to folders or directories and blobs are similar to files in our system.If you specify "http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob" it is similar to specifying "drive:folder/file".Hence when you access a blob through a url you actually fetch the blob(file) through http.

Comment: have you heard about SAS and all?